# Using Float is not working in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query

```
select 
    ExchangeRate,
    TotalAmt,
    ExchangeRate * TotalAmt TotalAmtConvert,
    ROUND(ExchangeRate * TotalARAmt, 0) TotalAmtRound 
from 
    dbo.Table
```

My results:

- ExchangeRate    **22450**
- TotalAmt        **16593.67**
- TotalAmtNoRound **372527891.5**
- TotalAmtRound   **372527891**

I want TotalAmtRound = **372527892**

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason use should not use FLOAT. It is a approximate datatype. Always use `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` datatypr

```
DECLARE @ExchangeRate  NUMERIC(22, 6) = 22450, 
        @TotalAmt      NUMERIC(22, 6) = 16593.67, 
        @ExchangeRate1 FLOAT = 22450, 
        @TotalAmt1     FLOAT = 16593.67 

SELECT numeric_result = Round(@ExchangeRate * @TotalAmt, 0), --Correct
       float_result = Round(@ExchangeRate1 * @TotalAmt1, 0), --Incorrect
       converted_numeric_result= Round(Cast(@ExchangeRate1 AS NUMERIC(22, 6)) 
                                         * Cast(@TotalAmt1 AS NUMERIC(22, 6)), 0) --Correct
```

when you select `@ExchangeRate1 * @TotalAmt1` it gives `372527891.49999994` but `@ExchangeRate * @TotalAmt` gives `372527891.5`.

**Result :**

```
╔════════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ numeric_result ║ float_result  ║ converted_numeric_result ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║      372527892 ║     372527891 ║                372527892 ║
╚════════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: thanks so much. I use CEILING() instead of ROUND(). It's working now.

Comment: @binhnguyenttm - But `ROUND` and `CEILING` functions are different. example `ROUND(12.2,0)` will give `12` and  `CEILING(12.2)` will give `13`

Comment: @binhnguyenttm - Here is the [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4874)

Comment: Thanks. I try to use your method and that is result i need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CEILING()` instead of `ROUND()`

> CEILING - Evaluates the value on the right side of the decimal and
>   returns the smallest integer greater than, or equal to, the specified
>   numeric expression and accepts one value:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1589/sql-server-rounding-functions--round-ceiling-and-floor/